# Displaying SplashScreen while user waits authentication from FirebaseAuth

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to display a splash screen on my App and I've managed to do it using a Handler and a Runnable object that constructs an intent and after 2 seconds changes activities to my login activity using the intent constructed

However, now I've set up the Firebase Authentication. I've tried to construct the intent to match the expected behavior:
(user signedIn --> show SplashScreen --> Skip LoginActivity)
(user notSignedIn --> show SplashScreen --> Show LoginActivity)
Here's the code I'm currently working on:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = null;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    /** Duration of wait **/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        if (user != null) {
                            // User is signed in, send to mainmenu
                            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            // User is signed out, send to register/login
                            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

    }
}
```

I've ommited the imports to shorten the code. The problem is that the app stay indefinetely in the splashscreen.

Comment: can i see your `manifest.xml` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using an AuthStateListener. You really just need to do the following without using an AuthStateListener:

```
             FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in, send to mainmenu
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class));
                } else {
                    // User is signed out, send to register/login
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
```